# Input Variable Type Validation

Tags: delphi, pascal, freepascal

The program for the 2015 skeleton program has some major validation issues in particular input type validation. For this procedure, how would ensure that the user enters SOMETHING and an INTEGER.

Procedure code:

```
Procedure GetMove(Var StartSquare, FinishSquare : Integer);
Begin
  Write('Enter coordinates of square containing piece to move (file first): ');
  Readln(StartSquare);
  Write('Enter coordinates of square to move piece to (file first): ');
  Readln(FinishSquare);
End;
```

I'm aware that this is basic although I strangely I have no idea.

Comment: Have you made *any effort* to do this yourself? Have you tested to see what happens if you try to enter something other than an integer? Have you tried entering nothing (just pressing the Enter key) and seeing what happens and what values you end up with in your variables?

Comment: And how do you think you can enter coordinates (plural) into a single integer?

Comment: If you really have *no idea*, then you need to go talk to your instructor. Ask for some hints, review the notes you took in class, and re-read the chapters of the book that this assignment accompanies.

Comment: Insolent and futile replies. For clarification; we didn't have any teachers. Before you instantly come to bigoted conclusions possibly ask before.

Answer (score 0):

You want to enter a coordinate like a spreadsheet cell reference. For instance, A1, B17. You need to look for the first digit and split the string at that point. Then validate the two parts. I'm presuming that just as for spreadsheets, the alpha part is the column, and the numeric part is the row.

```
function TryDecodeCoord(const coord: string; out col: string; out row: Integer): Boolean;
var
  FirstDigit: Integer;
begin
  FirstDigit := 1;
  while (FirstDigit <= Length(coord)) and (IsDigit(coord[FirstDigit])) do
    Inc(FirstDigit);

  if (FirstDigit = 1) or (FirstDigit > Length(coord)) then
  begin
    Result := False;
    Exit;
  end;
  col := Copy(coord, 1, FirstDigit - 1);

  if not TryStrToInt(Copy(coord, FirstDigit, MaxInt), row) then
  begin
    Result := False;
    Exit;
  end;

  Result := True;
end;
```

You'll need to implement `IsDigit`. Modern versions of Delphi provide RTL functions for this kind of thing. Otherwise you can readily check if the character is `>='0'` and `<='9'`.

I expect you'll want more validation than this. And possibly a way to convert the column from text to integer. But this should get you going.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance - what is the '2015 Skeleton program?'

Comment: @Hugh You need to ask the author of the question

Comment: @Hugh, the user is probably taking a programming class, and the instructor has issued to the students some files that will be used in this year's course. The students are expected to "flesh out" the provided skeleton code to implement the assignment(s). The user has probably directly quoted the assignment text in the first paragraph. The assignment's audience is assumed to be students of the class, and they would know what the phrase "2015 skeleton program" refers to. The user lacks the experience to realize that the text might need rephrasing to make sense to another audience, such as us.

Comment: aaaah - I thought must have been something relating to Fee Pascal .  Thanks.

Comment: @Hugh I'm just curious to know if I did something wrong

Comment: You may have earned the dv for assuming spreadsheet style coordinates. Basically, we have no idea, and anything would be a guess. We might guess chess due to moving pieces and the words "(file first)" - though I'm sure many other games use the same terminology.

Comment: @CraigYoung Chess coordinates would be parsed in the same way. Indeed they'd be simpler. Because you know that it is one alpha (A-H) and one number (1-8).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You missed the point. It's not about what cooridnate system is used; but the fact that you made a wild guess and gave an answer that could be irrelevant to the actual problem. (I was merely suggesting a _possible_ reason for the downvote you asked about.)

Comment: @CraigYoung The question could be more clear, but *the user enters SOMETHING and an INTEGER* seemed pretty clear to me.

Comment: _Something_ does not automatically imply a letter. In fact, I took it to mean the user is not allowed to enter "nothing". So the "something" the user must enter must also be an Integer. (Should be a compulsory module in programming 101: "How to avoid ambiguity")